# failure with creating an instance in specs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a model Ticket which has department_id, and Department with

```
enum name: { dept1: 0, dept2: 1, dept3: 2 }
```

I have seeded db with these three departments

```
Department.create(name: :dept1)
Department.create(name: :dept2)
Department.create(name: :dept3)
```

So I try to write specs on Ticket method

```
 def dept
   self.department.name.humanize
 end
```

here is an example

```
 describe '.dept' do   

   let!(:ticket){ create :ticket, department_id: Department.first.id }

   it 'should return right dept' do 
     expect(ticket.dept).to eq 'Dept1'
   end
 end
```

And I recieve an error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Validation failed: Department can't be blank
```

I'm a new guy to rails, so please i9f you don't mind explain me how to write such specs( with seeded db). Any advises would be very useful for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to refrain from seeding your database and instead create records that you need for each test.

```
describe '#dept' do
  let(:department) { create :department, title: 'dept1' }
  let(:ticket) { build :ticket, department: department }

  it 'should return right dept' do 
    expect(ticket.dept).to eq 'Dept1'
  end
end
```

Notice that I also changed `ticket` so it's generated by `build` instead of `create`. Based on what I see, it doesn't look like you need the overhead of persisting `ticket` to the database in order to run this particular test.

Also, another small point... But the "convention" (if such a thing exists) is to `describe` *instance methods* with hashes in front of them instead of a dot. (Dot denotes a *class method*.)

Comment: Thanks man! Convensions do exist I respect them much! I have mistype.

Comment: You're welcome. I tend to ignore conventions bullishly until I finally give in at a later date. :D

Comment: One more question on this. I think that it would be much more simple to set my seeded for test env. (Create a namespace in seeds or something like that? Is it a good idea?)